# Regex to remove port number in URL

Tags: regex, haproxy

I am trying to create a regex in Haproxy to remove the port number from the request url.

I have created a regex that will group the the url accordingly. But I am unable to replace the port number with white space in `reqrep` in Haproxy.

https://regex101.com/r/9TF0RE/1

What I have tried in Haproxy config

```
reqrep ^(?<=\/\/)([^:]+)\:[0-9]*\/(.*)     \1\ /\2
```

Comment: why is that tagged C?

Comment: Please explain your choice of tagging C. You otherwise suffer the risk of downvotes by people who consider that tag spamming.

Comment: Why you want to replace port number with space? Your regex seems to be working if you replace it with just `\1\/\2` where it just removes the colon and port number which should be your desired string

Comment: Since i did not have the language for Haprox, so I chose the language in which haproxy was based.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi: You are right, i only wanted to remove the port number and colon. But despite it does not work. Probably it has something to do with my haproxy cfg then.

Comment: @Vini: Yes at least in regex101 I can clearly see if you replace it with `\1\/\2` then it just removes colon and port. But in your regex, you also had a space `\1\ /\2` Hope you have removed that extra space. And if it doesn't work even after removal of space, then yes it could be that haproxy's regex engine might not be supporting something.

Comment: I tried also removing the space. i should dig deep into the haproxy then..

Comment: Just like this? https://regex101.com/r/9TF0RE/3